# What is the significance of the "binade" of a floating point value

Tags: swift, math, floating-point

Just noticed that Swift provides a ["binade" property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryfloatingpoint/1848292-binade) on floating point types. It's the floating point number with the a significand of 1 and the same exponent as the target value.  In shorter terms, `x.binade` is the largest power of 2 <= `x` (at least for `x` >= 0).

What's the actual significance of the `binade` of a number, particularly that it should be directly available as a property?

Comment: All values in a binade have the same precision.

Comment: But all values in any binade have the same precision, assuming the values are normalized.

Comment: Ie., that's a property of all normalized floating point values, and not a property of the binade?

Comment: I mean the same *absolute* precision (or equivalently, the same ULP).

Comment: For a non-standard function, this seems somewhat poorly specified/documented. What results does it give for subnormals, zeros, infinities, nans? What about negative numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most significant<sup>1</sup> feature of a binade (which is actually a set) that I can think of is that all its values have the same *absolute* precision.  Equivalently, they all have the same [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

---

<sub>1. No pun intended.</sub>

Comment: I don't think this answer provides any details why Swift has the `binade` property (or in other words a getter method) for a value of the same "binade set" with a unit significand. So the question is not about the "binade set" but about this property (method) and its importance.

Comment: Well, the “why does swift have a property “ part is extra credit and probably mostly opinion anyway, so this is partly my fault for a two-part question ;). It does answer the fundamental question which is that it describes a set, all the elements of which have the same ULP.

Comment: @DavidBerry, well, if you are satisfied with this answer, you should mark it as Accepted.